# Koobface or just ransomware scam?

Tags: malware

long time linux user. I use Arch Linux myself but I installed Ubuntu on another computer for someone else in the family. Today they told me they got a virus and didn't tell me until about 24 hours later. It said "You have been visited by the koobface virus call *phone number here* (I don't exactly remember, it had a 887 or 888 area code) I did some research and I'm not sure if it's the real thing or just a scam. I ran a scan on a windows laptop I have, none of the files that koobface may have installed (according to online articles) were on my system. If anybody knows anything about this anything to help me paranoia would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Either way, it sounds like the machine is [compromised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploit_(computer_security)).

Comment: I'm definitly going to reinstall Ubuntu on that computer and watch my other two for a few days. The idea of it being a worm is my biggest concern at this point.

Comment: @earthmeLon Umm, what if it was some fake pop-up on a shady website?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a cheap shot at social engineering.  A lot of fake virus alerts are simply displayed by visiting web pages by popups -- they can put anything they like in the popup, but of course, once you click to download the "remedy", the *real* trouble starts.